# Running nginx as non-root in Docker container gives permission denied error

Tags: linux, nginx, docker, permission-denied

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
EXPOSE 8000

# Install nginx
RUN apt-get update -q \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y -q \
                        nginx \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY ./index.html /usr/share/nginx/test/

RUN groupadd -r webgroup \
    && useradd -r -m -g webgroup webuser \
    && touch /run/nginx.pid \
    && chown -R webuser:webgroup /var/log/nginx /var/lib/nginx /run/nginx.pid 

USER webuser
CMD nginx
```

When I run it I get *Permission denied* on `/var/log/nginx`:

```
mikhails-mbp:test-docker-nginx mkuleshov$ docker run -p 8000:8000 mytest
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2016/10/02 17:02:51 [emerg] 5#0: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

If I get into the container with bash I see:

```
webuser@d190146a0e8d:/var/log/nginx$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-x--- 2 webuser webgroup 4096 Jun  2 15:16 .
drwxrwxr-x 8 root    syslog   4096 Oct  2 17:02 ..
```

How is it possible? During the above session I also cannot create files under that user.

**Thing that helped**: Removing the `/var/log/nginx` and recreating it again. But I have no idea why this happens.

There is no SELinux.

Has anyone encountered anything like that or is there anything I'm doing wrong?

P.S. Here is `docker info` if it can help

```
mikhails-mbp:test-docker-nginx mkuleshov$ docker info
Containers: 179
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 179
Images: 901
Server Version: 1.11.2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 1109
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 4.4.12-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.11.2 (TCL 7.1); HEAD : a6645c3 - Wed Jun  1 22:59:51 UTC 2016
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.955 GiB
Name: default
ID: 3K5S:3QBN:BXGY:FASS:VG6P:D4CS:UXRK:GYXB:HJQG:SIQH:F6KQ:N4BN
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 15
 Goroutines: 32
 System Time: 2016-10-02T17:08:51.355144074Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Username: mkuleshov
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
```

P.P.S. Here is a test repo with configs for that case: https://github.com/aides/test-docker-nginx

Comment: Did you not get this warning message when building the image: `[warn] 7#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges`

Comment: This warning appears when I have 'user' directive in the `nginx.conf`. Here I'm running the master process as a non-super-user and I don't have a 'user' directive in the `nginx.conf`. I'm also not sure I'm not wrong here, so any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely adding your user into adm group will solve your issue.

Try sudo usermod -aG adm webuser

More details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/421684/cant-access-apache-error-logs

Comment: This works! I wonder though what this magic is all about. I will mark this one as accepted if no other reason appears.